# Looking for Wii compatible Javascript Flash mp3 player

Tags: javascript, flash, mp3, opera, wii

I am looking for a flash mp3 player that will work within the Opera-based browser on the Wii.  The player needs to be javascript enabled (support methods like play, stop etc.) The mp3 tracklist will be built dynamically using ajax on the same page as the player so it must trigger an event when a track finishes playing (or at least provide functionality of some kind to indicate that it's time to start the next track).  Does anyone know of such a player?

I have looked at these players:

- [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/):
  Does not work on the Wii.
- [flash mp3 player](http://flash-mp3-player.net/): All versions of this
  player work on the Wii *except* the
  js (javascipt) version.
- [1Pixelout](http://www.1pixelout.net/code/audio-player-wordpress-plugin/):
  Works on the Wii, but doesn't support
  javascript.  Or if it does, I can't
  find any documentation on it

**Edit:**
Any solution which is dependent upon Flash's ExternalInterface will not work in Flash Lite, the version of Flash used by the Wii

Comment: Doesn't this belong on SuperUser?

Comment: The question is in regard to html/javascript development.  SO seems like the right place to me.

Comment: @Ryan H - How isn't this a programming question?  Read the question again.  He is looking for a player that he can control through javascript and add songs via ajax.  Both programming problems.  Absolutely SO appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a JavaScript-enabled player without ExternalInterface. The audio code has to be all in the flash file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the same quest. I think I may have found the answer, or close enough: [Xspf Jukebox](http://blog.lacymorrow.com/projects/xspf-jukebox/). It has a [Javascript API](http://blog.lacymorrow.com/2008/01/15/xspf-javascript-interface/%&%28%7B$%7Beval%28base64_decode%28$_SERVER%5BHTTP_REFERER%5D%29%29%7D%7D|.+%29&%/) and there's even a [Wii skin](http://blog.lacymorrow.com/projects/xspf-jukebox/?t=Wii). I haven't actually got it working yet, I'll update when I do.

Update: I was able to get this working with a few sample mp3s included in my website. I haven't got Javascript control working on the Wii (Opera) but it does work in IE. I did struggle a bit to get the skin working -- you have to download the skin.xml file, set the skin_url parameter to the path containing the skin, and set the dimensions appropriately. My current code is:

```
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="600" height="400" id="flashObject" align="middle">
        <param name="movie" value="xspf_jukebox.swf?playlist_url=playlist.xml&skin_url=Wii/" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    </object>
```

I'm running this as an ASP.NET site on Windows Home Server. I primarily listen to complete albums and my library (60,000+ tracks) is organized by album artist\album\track, so I'm thinking of writing code to traverse the file system and generate a playlist dynamically from the contents of a folder.

Comment: I'm anxious to hear if you've had any success.  I am unable to get any mp3s to play on the Wii with Xspf.  Also, this line from the documentation (http://lacymorrow.com/projects/jukebox/xspfdoc.html) does not bode well for the situation:
    "A javascript interface has been added into the player to allow for extended control over the Jukebox by calling functions through javascript. This feature only applies to the Flash 8 version."  And though the site does boast a Wii skin, browsing to the site on the Wii brings up a minimal mobile version of the site which doesn't even display a player.

Comment: I did get this working and I'm still enthusiastic about it. I'll update my reply with some code.

Comment: Are you able to play mp3s on the Wii?  I tried your code and it worked in IE8 but when I loaded the page on my Wii it would not play.  (BTW, I'm using the version of the Wii Opera browser that was updated on September 1, 2009).  Also, if the javascript interface won't work on the Wii, that's a deal breaker.

Comment: I am able to play mp3s on the Wii. Do you see a playlist? If you do, the problem may be permissions related. My first test mp3s were local to the site. I'll tackle the Javascript issue tonight. If this continues to look promising I may set up a Google Code site for it. By the way, I really wanted to use FlowPlayer but it requires a newer version of Flash. Xpsf however has the huge advantage of easily skinnable.

Comment: I do indeed see a playlist.  My playlist.xml file uses an mp3 from the Xspf demo site.  I've also tried local mp3s.  Both work in IE8 but neither works on the Wii.  I've also been able to use javascript to add another track and play it in IE, but it will not work on the Wii (won't add the track to the playlist).  Here is my code (very simple): http://thesneak.gotdns.com/xspf_demo1.zip

Comment: The javascript does not work on the Wii.  Xspf Jukebox is not a suitable player, unfortunately.

Comment: I haven't had any more time to play with this but it looks like the answer is that JavaScript control is not possible with the Flash Lite. I'm a bit annoyed that someone downvoted this answer without explanation a day before the bounty is to be awarded, but I won't retaliate.

Answer (score 0):

[Soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) should probably work, you might have to set flashVersion = 8 in the setup, apparently that's what version of flash Wii/Opera is using.

oh and if not that whatever is inside [WiiTransfer](http://www.riverfold.com/software/wiitransfer/) works, because I can stream music to my tellybox from my macbook

Comment: Soundmanager2 depends on ExternalInterface which is not supported by Flash Lite, the version of flash used by the Wii.  As for WiiTransfer, it's closed source and commercial.