# Flash Lite 3.1 + javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, mp3, wii

I know almost nothing about actionscript.  Is it possible for Flash Lite 3.1 to use the flash.external.ExternalInterface to allow javascript interaction?

If it is possible, can someone explain why [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/0.2.5/jQuery.jPlayer.0.2.5.source.zip) (open source) doesn't work on the Wii?

I have been [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617176/looking-for-wii-compatible-javascript-flash-mp3-player) for a flash mp3 player that will work on the Nintendo Wii and which supports javascript interaction (for instance, I need to be able to assign event handlers like TrackEnded() and be able to issue PlayTrack() commands) and haven't found anything.  There are many flash mp3 players out there, but none of them are able to do what I require on the Wii.  This leads me to wonder if what I'm after is not actually possible.  Is there something about Flash Lite 3.1 (which is used by the Opera browser on the Wii) that precludes javascript interaction with flash objects?

Comment: any luck finding a flash lite player that plays mp3 files? I'm looking for one too...

Comment: I have not had any luck finding a flash mp3 player that meets my needs.  If your needs are less restrictive than mine, you might be able to use one of the players mentioned in the 2nd link.

Comment: hmmm, I know adobe air works on wii and that definately has externalinterface. Worth investigating maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from ezekielDFM is wrong - i think

my understanding is that the version 3.1 flash lite plugin used in opera on the wii has a knackered externalinterface - so will not work - and there is not much you can do to fix it - so you have to work around it - though i am not sure how - maybe with localconnection...

ezekielDFM - feel free to correct me if you have actually created a swf with externalinterface and observed it to work on the wii ! - regardless of what the docs may claim

EDIT : here is a hand written replacement - though i haven't tested it
https://github.com/aadsm/customExternalInterface/blob/master/src/ExternalInterface.as

Answer (score -1):

You can use ActionScript 1.0 and 2.0 when developing for Flash Lite 3. ActionScript 2.0 does have the ExternalInterface API, therefore you can do what you're asking. Here's a link to the AS2 ExternalInterface docs:

http://flash-reference.icod.de/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

As far as what version of Flash Lite is supported you will need to check the device capabilities of the mobile device.

Comment: It isn't available on the Wii, sadly.